# Integrating $f(t)=t|t|\sin t$ and calculating the Fourier series of it

Tags: integration, fourier-series

I was going to calculate the Fourier series of

$f(t)=t|t|\sin (n\pi t)$, on the interval $[-1,1]$, with period $T=2$ but the modulus of *t* got me thinking.

I did

\begin{equation}
a_n=\int_{-1}^1t|t|\sin n\pi tdt=
\int_{-1}^1t^2\sin n\pi tdt=\frac{4}{n^2\pi^2}\big(-1\big)^n
\end{equation}

Then I did

\begin{equation}
b_0=\int_{-1}^1t|t|\sin n\pi tdt=
\int_{-1}^1t^2\sin n\pi tdt=0
\end{equation}

and finally

\begin{equation}
a_0=\int_{-1}^1t|t|\sin n\pi tdt=\int_{-1}^1t|t|\cdot 0dt=0
\end{equation}

and got therefore:

\begin{equation}
\mathscr{F}\bigg[f(t)=t|t|\sin (n\pi t)\bigg]_{-1}^1=4\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\big(-1\big)^n}{n^2\pi^2}
\end{equation}

But I fear that the simplification $t|t|=t^2$ is not correct. Any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe separate the integrals in two parts. when $-1\leq t\leq 0$ you can use $t|t|=-t^2$ and for $0\leq t \leq 1$ you use $t|t|=t^2$.

Comment: Thanks, this seems a good idea.

Comment: I did what you suggest, and the calculation seems quite long. In fact, it is so long that it gets a little messy.

Comment: Maybe you can take advantage of simetry then.